# R in SQL Server: Output data frame into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, sql-server-2016

This probably has a simple answer but I cannot figure it out as I'm still getting a hang of working with R in SQL Server. I have a piece of code that reads in data from a SQL Server table, executes in R and returns a data frame.

```
execute sp_execute_external_script
    @language=N'R',
    @script=N'inp_dat=InputDataSet
    inp_dat$NewCol=max(inp_dat$col1,inp_dat$col2)
    new_dat=inp_dat
    OutputDataSet=new_dat'
    @input_data_1=N'select * from IM_COMP_TEST_SQL2016.dbo.temp_table';
```

I want to insert new_dat into a SQL Server table (`select * into new_table from new_dat`). How do I go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As shown in this [tutorial](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4126/sql-server-2016-r-services-executing-r-code-in-sql-server/), you can use `INSERT INTO ... EXEC` in a previously created table with columns aligning to script's dataframe return:

```sql
INSERT INTO Table1
execute sp_execute_external_script
    @language=N'R',
    @script=N'inp_dat <- InputDataSet
              inp_dat$NewCol <- max(inp_dat$col1,inp_dat$col2)
              new_dat <- inp_dat',
    @input_data_1=N'SELECT * FROM IM_COMP_TEST_SQL2016.dbo.temp_table',
    @output_data_1=N'newdat';
```

However, to use the make-table query may require `OPENQUERY()` or `OPENROWSET()` using an ad-hoc distributed query as described in this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1228165/1422451) to return the output of stored procedure:

**Stored Procedure**

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.R_DataFrame

AS

BEGIN
    execute sp_execute_external_script
        @language=N'R',
        @script=N'inp_dat <- InputDataSet
                  inp_dat$NewCol <- max(inp_dat$col1,inp_dat$col2)
                  new_dat <- inp_dat',
        @input_data_1=N'SELECT * FROM IM_COMP_TEST_SQL2016.dbo.temp_table',
        @output_data_1=N'newdat';

        -- ADD ALL COLUMN TYPES;
        WITH RESULT SETS (("newdat" [col1] varchar(20), [col2] double, [col3] int ...));
END
GO
```

**Action Query**

```sql
SELECT * INTO Table1 
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=(local);Trusted_Connection=yes;',
                'EXEC dbo.R_DataFrame')
```

Comment: While trying your first solution, to directly insert into a table, I run into the following error: Procedure expects parameter '@params' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'. Would you be aware as to what is causing this? The table being inserted into has the correct number of columns expected and I am not passing any parameters. Thanks.