# How to output values from sp_execute_external_script into table

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas

Having the following code, how can I output the values from the external python script into a sql table that I can query after.

```
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script 
@language = N'Python',
@script = N'
            import pandas as pd
            import numpy as np

            rd = np.random.randn(100)
            df = pd.DataFrame(rd).describe()
            print(df)'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39841023/r-in-sql-server-output-data-frame-into-a-table) should be useful. It uses R, but the end goal remains the same.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful.

Answer (score 7):

Indeed, as the R version shows, consider `INSERT INTO myTable ...` using results from the Python executed script in TSQL, specifying *@output_data*. However, first create table to be appended to, aligning columns and types accordingly.

Additionally, since you use `describe()`, consider renaming columns prior to output. Finally, *pandas* is included by default for the Python Machine Learning Services in SQL Server 2016 as mentioned in this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/tutorials/run-python-using-t-sql), so no need to import (possibly same with numpy).

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myTable;

CREATE TABLE myTable (
    [aggregate] varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [value] float NOT NULL
    )
GO

INSERT INTO myTable    
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script 
@language = N'Python',
@script = N'import numpy as np

            rd = np.random.randn(100)
            df = pandas.DataFrame(rd).describe().reset_index().rename(columns={"index":"aggregate", 0:"value"})',
@output_data_1_name = N'df';

GO
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: What if you were dealing with a dictionary?

Comment: @Hiram, not quite sure what you mean but convert dictionary to pandas data frame. For more, please ask a new question.

Answer (score -1):

```
declare @py nvarchar(max);

set @py = N'from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

rdd = {"documents": [{"id": "1", "score": 0.97},{"id": "2","score": 0.87},{"id": "3", "score": 0.78}],"errors": []}
print(type(rdd))

df = json_normalize(rdd, "documents")
print(df)
print(type(df))
'; 

drop table if exists apiresults
create table apiresults (id int, score float)

insert into apiresults
exec sp_execute_external_script 
    @language = N'Python',
    @script = @py,
    @output_data_1_name =N'df'

select * from apiresults
```